Unable to pass annotations to helm
I've created a helm chart to deploy a simple container application to an AKS cluster, but I'm trying to get the LoadBalancer to use a pre-existing static public ip called mypip inside of myrg and can't seem to set the annotations to do that.
My values.yaml file has the following:
service:
  type: LoadBalancer
  port: 8080
  targetport: 8080
  annotations: 
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/azure-load-balancer-resource-group: "myrg"
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/azure-pip-name: "mypip"
    

And I've also tried to set the values on the command line (not sure if the back-slashes are needed here but I've seen them in other examples):
helm install helloworld . --set controller.service.annotations.service.beta.kubernetes.io/azure-load-balancer-resource-group=myrg --set controller.service.annotations.service.beta.kubernetes.io/azure-pip-name=mypip

Each time I deploy the external_ip stays in pending:
E:\Documents\work\helm\helloworld>kubectl get --namespace default svc -w helloworld

NAME         TYPE           CLUSTER-IP   EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)          AGE
helloworld   LoadBalancer   10.1.17.71   <pending>     8080:31914/TCP   4s

And the output of "kubectl describe" is telling me that it's trying to create a new pip and is not showing the annotations I have set.
Can anyone advise what I'm doing wrong?  Thank you.

In order to deploy a simple container application to an AKS cluster with a pre-existing static public ip
Once you have your public IP, create a helmchart
helm create helloworld

cd into it and modify the values.yaml file to include the annotations
Example-
replicaCount: 1

image:
  repository: nginx
  pullPolicy: IfNotPresent
  tag: ""

imagePullSecrets: []
nameOverride: ""
fullnameOverride: ""

serviceAccount:
  create: true
  annotations: {}
  name: ""

podAnnotations: {}
podLabels: {}

podSecurityContext: {}
securityContext: {}

service:
  type: LoadBalancer
  port: 80
  annotations:
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/azure-load-balancer-resource-group: "arkorg"
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/azure-pip-name: "mypip"

ingress:
  enabled: false
  annotations: {}
  hosts:
    - host: chart-example.local
      paths:
        - path: /
          pathType: ImplementationSpecific
  tls: []

resources: {}
livenessProbe:
  httpGet:
    path: /
    port: http
readinessProbe:
  httpGet:
    path: /
    port: http

autoscaling:
  enabled: false
  minReplicas: 1
  maxReplicas: 100
  targetCPUUtilizationPercentage: 80

nodeSelector: {}
tolerations: []
affinity: {}

and modify your service.yaml as well under templates, which you will find inside your helm directory if you do ls
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: {{ include "helloworld.fullname" . }}
  labels:
    {{- include "helloworld.labels" . | nindent 4 }}
  annotations:
    {{- with .Values.service.annotations }}
    {{- toYaml . | nindent 4 }}
    {{- end }}
spec:
  type: {{ .Values.service.type }}
  ports:
    - port: {{ .Values.service.port }}
      targetPort: {{ .Values.service.targetPort | default .Values.service.port }}
      protocol: TCP
  selector:
    {{- include "helloworld.selectorLabels" . | nindent 4 }}

save it and deploy the helm chart
helm install helloworld . --namespace default


check the service status
kubectl get svc helloworld -n default


external Ip now visible.
In your case, your annotations in the values.yaml is correct. However, the command to set the annotations is incorrect. You need to enclose the annotation keys and values in quotes and use the --set-string flag to ensure that the values are treated as strings. Here is the corrected command:
helm install helloworld . --set-string controller.service.annotations."service\.beta\.kubernetes\.io/azure-load-balancer-resource-group"="myrg" --set-string controller.service.annotations."service\.beta\.kubernetes\.io/azure-pip-name"="mypip"


References:

Use a static public IP address and DNS label with the Azure Kubernetes Service (AKS) load balancer


Thank you very much for this, I actually figured it out last night that the annotations had to go under the templates\service.yaml, but I really appreciate you sharing this information.  It took me a long time to figure it out and the documentation is really lacking I felt.  One thing which still confuses me is when you edit the configuration under service.yaml how you are defining the annotations for just the LoadBalancer service as the type field is set to:  type: {{ .Values.service.type }} so it looks as though it applies this for all services, not just the LoadBalancer?

Ah I think I understand your post now, so you've basically extended the default service.yaml to get it to recognise the annotations in values.yaml.  It doesn't seem to do this by default when you check the default service.yaml template created from a "helm create", the annotations section is missing completely.

Is the fact that the annotations section is missing from the default template/service.yaml file a bug?  I am not seeing the requirement to add this documented anywhere?

Nope, not a bug, Helm charts created with helm create provide a very basic template. When you want to add annotations to a k8s service, you need to customize the service.yaml template in your Helm chart.
